# ui router request parameter with custom value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to send request like this:

```
/users?page=1&order[name]=asc
```

but ui-router does not handle this syntax how can I pass params to fix that. 
Here is my code snippet:

```
var params = {
    'page': $state.params.page,
    'sort[title]': $state.params.order
  };

Restangular.all('api/orders').getList(params).then(function(data){
    orders = data;
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need UI router here? As I understand you just want to send ajax request (probably GET), yes?

Comment: Please be a lot more specific about your problem, what you are needing router to do and show code related to this

Comment: Yeah, your are right, i need to send it via Rectangular GET request, but i assign parameters to query from ui-route state provider params. With such params as page=2 there is no problem, everything works fine. But when i wand some specific request order[title]=asc i can't figure out how to do it.